# Illustrator Blob Brush & Draw Inside Function - Best way to trim excess brush strokes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I’ve been having a lot of fun with the blob brush and utilizing the Draw Inside function to fill in my vector shape. 
However, I need a clean path of just the perimeter of my vector shape (for cutting purposes) and I need to remove all of the excess brush strokes that still appear as paths. What is the quickest and most efficient way to trim away the excess brush strokes after using the draw inside function? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Make a Transparency Mask**

- Create a 100% black **Compound Shape** over your drawing leaving free the visible area
- Select the *Drawing* and the *Compound Shape*
- From the **Transparency Panel** > **Make Mask**
- Uncheck **Clip**
- Click the left square from the **Transparency Panel** to go back to the editing area

[image: INVERSE MASK]

Answer (score 0):

My way to do it:

1- I expand it, first.

2- Ungroup it.

3- Pathfinder -> divide.

This will cut all paths masked (outside) by the clipping mask.

I use it sometimes, then I decided to make an action.

See the image below...

[image]